# how do I get the SUM for my_hit count and more_info

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum

Here is my table.

[image: My Table]

Here is what I have so far and everything works, but... The only problem is I need a total count of the more_info column too. How would I go about this?

```
SELECT *, SUM(hit_count) as 'view_count'
    FROM $table_name
    WHERE create_date >='".$fromdate."' 
    AND create_date<='".$todate."'
    AND post_author ='".$_POST['pps_user_id']."'  
    GROUP BY post_id desc
```

We are getting the total for the hit_count, but I also want to get a total for each different jsn string in the more_info area and output that too when Grouping by post_id desc

Comment: Isn't more_info a character/ string? What are your trying to count? The unique values from record to record? (`COUNT(DISTINCT more_info)`)

Comment: sum() totals up numbers. you're trying to stuff in STRINGS. maybe you want `count()` instead?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion....We are getting the total for the hit count, but I also want to get a total for each different jsn string in the more_info area and output that too when Grouping by post_id desc. Is this possible?

Comment: I think that will have to be done in PHP. Add this column `GROUP_CONCAT(more_info) AS more_info` to your SELECT statement. Then using PHP, you will have to parse out the values in that column and SUM them.

Comment: If you need to query `more_info` data you should be storing it as a table, not as a blob of JSON.

Comment: @AgRizzo, thanks that did it! Now how can I parse out the values as you say and and sum them? an example would be great!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this answers your question but you can parse out these values using SUBSTRING_INDEX like below

```
SELECT post_id,jsn_string,SUM(jsn_count) as jsn_count
FROM
(SELECT post_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(more_info,'"',4),'"',-1) as jsn_string,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(more_info,':',-3) + 0 as jsn_count
FROM yourtable
UNION All
SELECT post_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(more_info,'"',8),'"',-1) as jsn_string,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(more_info,':',-1) + 0 as jsn_count
FROM yourtable
)T1
WHERE jsn_string != ''
GROUP BY post_id,jsn_string
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a51b/14)